# Google Search Console not showing proper other pages results (they are indexed)

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, google-search-console, search

i have a website and than i have a wordpress blog in /blog route of that site they are kind of independent for now since i havent done any internal linking on them so i created this new post n my blog and submitted it for indexing it got positive results and its also showing up on google but i cant see its results on google search console does any one know why?

side note: i havent submitted site map for now.(and if its because of site map than is it possible to view results without sitemap?)

Comment: From my experience, usually there could be delays in search console reporting. Btw, a properly linked architecture of a site would help both humans and crawlers to access even the deepest of the pages.

Comment: Google search console will show everything eventually, but it could take months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GSC doesn't need a sitemap to include your page in it's results.  Read the [Sitemap Paradox.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)  The pages that you have that aren't linked to, probably should have a sitemap, or create links to them (the preferred way).

If you don't see a page in GSC, you can resubmit it to see if Google is still including it in the index. However, as Kannan mentioned, it can take awhile for pages to show up in GSC.  I've seen it take a couple of weeks for a new page to be shown in GSC.

In my experience, Google may 'read' your page when it's submitted, but it may be several days or weeks before Google will parse it and index it.